# Logging log4j and Null object

Tags: java, logging, log4j, nullpointerexception

I wonder that can I avoid NullPointerException in _log.info.
I have 1 null object (obj) and then

```
_log.info("obj id: " + obj.objId());
```

In this case I want _log printout that obj.objId() is null and not throw an exception :-? anyone know how to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about: `_log.info(String.format("obj id: %s", (obj == null ? obj : obj.objId())));`?

Comment: ah, I see, create my own method which include code check obj null or not, thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's not an issue with log4j, that's an issue with your program

You could do something along the lines of ....

```
_log.info("obj id: " + (obj == null ? null : obj.objId()));
```

I don't think the problem is that the ID is null, I think, from what you are saying, the `obj` is null, thus the reference to `obj.objId()` is causing the NPE

Comment: you are right, but I want it dont throw exception, however, just an idea :))